# ElasticSearch sort data during index creation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to implement ElasticSearch on my WooCommerce site (shoe store) using OpenSearch. I want certain products to be at the top of the search results.
If someone searches for "basketball", I want to return all products sorted this way:

1. Shoes that have the word "Adidas" in the product name
2. Shoes that have the word "Nike" in the product name
3. Shoes that have "basketball" in the product name (field: post_title)
4. Shoes that have "basketball" in the description (field: post_content)

I want this done during the index creation, not during search.

```
$client->indices()->create([
    'index' => $index,
    'body' => [
        'mappings' => $mappings
    ],
    // I read somewhere that can set "score" here somewhere
]);
```

I think this can be achieve by setting the search parameters like this, but again, I want the sorting done during index creation, not during search:

```
$params = [
    'index' => $config['index-prefix'] . $type,
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'post_title' => [
                                'query' => 'Adidas',
                                'boost' => 5
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'post_title' => [
                                'query' => 'Nike',
                                'boost' => 4
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'post_title' => [
                                'query' => $query,
                                'boost' => 3
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            'post_content' => [
                                'query' => $query,
                                'boost' => 2
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'match' => [
                            '*' => [
                                'query' => $query
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        'query_string' => [
                            'query' => "*" . $query . "*",
                            'fields' => ['*']
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'query_string' => [
                            'query' => $query,
                            'fields' => ['*']
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ],
        'fields' => ['id'],
        'sort' => ['_score', ['id' => 'desc']],
        'size' => 20
    ],
];
$results = $client->search($params);
```